# How to handle MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException and set a custom error message in spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, exception

I'm making an REST API and, while trying purposefully wrong inputs to force errors, I stumbled in this one:

`2023-12-01T19:43:11.427-03:00  WARN 23912 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; For input string: "43178asdas"]`

The body of the response was as follows:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2023-12-01T22:43:11.433+00:00",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; For input string: \"43178asdas\"",
    "path": "/objectName/43178asdas"
}
```

I want to make a custom message for the error, making it clearer that the expected input was type Long, but instead the request received a type String, but I'm not managing to handle the exception.

What I tried:

```
public class ThisObjectInvalidaException extends TypeMismatchException {
    public ThisObjectInvalidaException(String msg){
        super(msg);
    }
}
```

and

```
public SaidObject consult(Long param) throws ThisObjectInvalidaException {
        try {
            return this.objRepository.findById(identifier)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "No object found with the following IDENTIFIER: " + identifier + "."));
        } catch (TypeMismatchException e){
            throw new ThisObjectInvalidaException("The IDENTIFIER you entered is invalid, as it should contain only numbers.");
        }
    }
```

Maybe I'm missing something in the error type or so, but not sure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add ExceptionHandler to your controller.

Example:

```
@RestController
public class YourController {

    // Your endpoint mappings

    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleTypeMismatch(MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException ex) {
        String error = "The IDENTIFIER you entered is invalid, as it should contain only numbers.";
        return new ResponseEntity<>(error, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

As an alternative solution you can create the custom exception and throw it.

Example 2:

```
    public class IdentifierFormatException extends RuntimeException {

    public IdentifierFormatException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

}
```

and then add it to exception handler:

```
@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleTypeMismatch(MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException ex) {
        throw new IdentifierFormatException("The IDENTIFIER you entered is invalid, as it should contain only numbers.");
    }
```