# How to catch exception raised by Jackson before reaching controller in spring?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I need to handle an exception which is raised before controller level in my spring mvc application. I tried with @ControllerAdvice but this is not working because the exception is raised before controller. Infact if my endpoint is expecting a json like this:

```
{"number": "10"}
```

but I give

```
 {"number": "'"}
```

I get an exception MethodArgumentExceptionHandler that I'm unable to catch before to customize the message. I think this happens because Jackson throw the exception before, infact if i debug my code it never enter inside the controller with the malformed json input. How can i handle/catch the exception to be able to customize the exception message? Please help me.

EDIT2: I understood the problem. I have a custom ErorrController which set the error code of the exception in a custom header. I need to change this error message based on the exception received

Comment: Could you please post the controller method and the body class you expect too? We would have a better understanding of your problem then

Comment: Also, you maybe get MethodArgumentNotValidException, not a "MethodArgumentExceptionHandler" (maybe you confused the handler class with the exception class)

Comment: I added the exception text

Comment: @pochopsp i added new info

Comment: Did you try to add a MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException handler in your controller?
Something like the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77588496/how-to-handle-methodargumenttypemismatchexception-and-set-a-custom-error-message

Answer (score 1):

In a Spring application that uses Jackson for JSON processing, you may encounter exceptions related to JSON deserialization or serialization. To catch exceptions raised by Jackson before reaching the controller, you can use an ExceptionHandler in combination with a custom HandlerExceptionResolver. This approach allows you to handle exceptions globally across your Spring application.
you can use

> @ExceptionHandler
> and this is a simple Example to help you to understand :

```
  @ExceptionHandler(JsonProcessingException.class)
public ResponseEntity<String> handleJsonProcessingException(JsonProcessingException ex) {
    // Log the exception or perform other actions
    // You can customize the response based on your requirements
    return new ResponseEntity<>("Error processing JSON: " + ex.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

if you need more , just ask .or show the code

Comment: Please be aware of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1

Answer (score 0):

It would be good if you provided some code. However, if you are using controller advice, you can try this solution.

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class CustomExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    // Handle JSON parse exceptions
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMessageNotReadable(HttpMessageNotReadableException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        String error = "Malformed JSON request";
        return buildResponseEntity(new ApiError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, error, ex));
    }

    // Handle other/internal exceptions
    @ExceptionHandler(value = { InternalException.class })
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleGenericException(Exception ex) {
        String error = "An unexpected error occurred";
        return buildResponseEntity(new ApiError(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, error, ex)); // this is an example
    }

    private ResponseEntity<Object> buildResponseEntity(ApiError apiError) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(apiError, apiError.getStatus());
    }
}
```